# Default Azure SQL DB pricing when created automatically through EF Core

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

We have a web app that uses Entity Framework Core. If it is given a connection string to a database on Azure that doesn't exist, calling `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` will create it automatically. This is great for our development branches as we call it with a connection string with a database name equal to the branch name and it creates the Azure SQL DB resource automatically.

When we started it seemed by default to be creating databases with the DTU pricing model and the 'Basic' tier, which is the cheapest option at 5 GBP/month, ideal for development branches.

However it seems to have changed and the default pricing model is now vCore General Purpose Generation 5 which comes out at 320+ GBP/month! This is quite a difference that we noticed on our invoice!

Is there a way to specify the default Azure SQL DB configuration created? This might not be anything to do with entity framework but could be a setting on Azure at the subscription level.

Answer (score 0):

Issue a CREATE DATABASE statement with the correct option before running migrate, or even better use an ARM template and deploy that during release.

Comment: +1 for an ARM template, you could then also create the whole environment as part of the pipeline therefore also testing out its creation and then its validity in your tests.