# Database scales without permission

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm building a series of services in Azure which use SQL Azure (via a code-first Entity Framework Core) for some of it's storage. To save money during development time, I have the DB (where I really don't care about perf) set to the lowest Basic tier (just 5 DTUs which cost ~$5/month).

Periodically, I will run a simple shell app which calls 
dataContext.Database.EnsureDeleted() followed by dataContext.Database.EnsureCreated() and then some basic data insertions so I can start from a clean/known place.

Just one problem: every-time I do the DB gets auto-scaled to "General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCores" which costs $277.54 a month... waaay more than I want/need/can afford, and should I not remember to scale back down to basic, I end up spending a lot.

I'm early enough in development that going an ARM template route [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124429/default-azure-sql-db-pricing-when-created-automatically-through-ef-core) seems overkill.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At this time the default tier offered by Azure when creating a new database is "General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCores". My suggestion is to use an ARM template or a PowerShell script to make sure you create an Azure Database assigned to the Basic tier. [Here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/11/06/azure-sql-database-with-powershell.aspx) you will find and example using PowerShell.